# How do I make voltage step on proteus?

Tags: proteus

I'm making this circuit on proteus but i don't know how to make this voltage step

Please tell me how to make voltage step on proteus.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Proteus but it should have one of two things in there:

1. A voltage source which can have specified a period `T`, pulse width `Ton`, rise and fall times `tr` and `tf`, lower and upper voltages `V1` and `V2`, a delay `Td`, and an optional number of cycles `N`. With these you need to specify a pulse width of `Ton=1` and a falling time of `tr=1m` (you can use `1u` if you really want sharp times, but `1m` should be enough and too low values may cause problems). Some SPICE simulators allow not specifying `T`, which means it goes indefinitely, but to be in the safe side set `T` to be greater than your total simulation time. E.g. if you plan to simulate for 10 sec then make `T=11` (anything greater). Then make `V1=10` and `V2=0`, while leaving `tr=0` and `Td=0` since they are not needed.
2. A PWL (Piece-Wise Linear) source, which can have pairs of value-time points. E.g. for your case you can set these to `0, 10, 1, 10, +1m 0`. This says at time `0` the value is `10`, then at time `1` the value is still `10`, and at `+1m` compared to the previous time point (`1`) the value is `0`. Just like above, you could have `+1u` if you really need very steep slopes, but I doubt you'll ned it.

Additionally, in SPICE there are also behavioural sources, and if Proteus has them then you can write the equivalent of `if(time < 1, 10, 0)`.

To be on the safe side I'll add: don't forget to add a ground node, since everything needs to be referenced to it.

Comment: thanks! i will try it